# ubuntu smart card authentication failed using self signed certificate

Tags: ubuntu, smartcard, pam

I am using smart card to do authentication under *Ubuntu 12.04.5 TLS*.
The smart card I use is *Gemalto v2 .net* .

I followed the instructions listed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1557180)

To summarize my steps:

1. Firstly I installed the necessary software, and make *pkcs11-tool* read/write the card OK.
2. I configure the `pam sudo` to use choose smart card authentication.
3. I generate the self signed certificate using the *Openssl engine-pkcs11* plugin. then register the certificate with the Ubuntu, and  the key and certificate are written into the smart card.
4. Finally, I execute command: `sudo -i`

Then, I am prompted to input the smart card PIN code.
After input, I get some error like:

```
DEBUG:cert_vfy.c:350: Adding hash dir '/etc/pam_pkcs11/cacerts' to CACERT checks
ERROR:pam_pkcs11.c:595: verify_certificate() failed: certificate is invalid: self signed certificate
ERROR:pam_pkcs11.c:658: no valid certificate which meets all requirements found
Error 2336: No matching certificate found
```

Does anybody know what's the meaning of the error?

Answer (score 0):

When you write `sudo -i`, the user is `root` By default.

So, if you generate the signature for another user in your card, you must write this command :

`# sudo - TheUserName -i`